# Dynamic complication using the wrong using statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 application that uses default layout in /views/shared folder but it includes a using statement using the name of the prior assembly.

```
#pragma checksum "D:\websites\Sitecore8.2\Website\views\shared\DefaultMutualPayLayout.cshtml" "{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}" "6B4F2C8927D658C5F89E57B00FE5CA76B337ABFE"
Line 2:    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 3:    // <auto-generated>
Line 4:    //     This code was generated by a tool.
Line 5:    //     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.36415
Line 6:    //
Line 7:    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will 
  be lost if
Line 8:    //     the code is regenerated.
Line 9:    // </auto-generated>
Line 10:   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Line 26:       using System.Web.Routing;
Line 27:       using Sitecore 8.2.Web;
Line 28:       using Sitecore.Mvc;
Line 29:       using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation;
```

The Line 27 using Sitecore 8.2.Web should be SitecoreXP.Web; The current binary.

I've searched all configs thinking that it was coming from a configuration statement but I can not find where this is coming from and how to have it use the correct using statement.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

In the Views folder the web.config file contains a section

The wrong namespace was listed there. Once changed to the correct namespace everything started working.